# Non-trivial positive combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$. Are the following equivalent?

1. There are $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \geq 0$ not all zero such that $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\alpha_kv_k = 0$
2. For every linear function $L: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ there is $1 \leq k \leq n$ such that $L(v_k) \geq 0$

I will try to prove the implication (2) $\implies$ (1), because the converse is easier. I will assume that (1) is false, and show that I can construct a linear function $L: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that L(v_k) < 0 for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

Let $K$ be the kernel of the morphism $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$ determined by $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n) \mapsto \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\alpha_kv_k$. I will use induction on $\text{dim}(K)$.

If $\text{dim}(K) = 0$, then $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are linearly independent and we can define $L$ such that $L(v_k) = -1$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

If $\text{dim}(K) = 1$, let $(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$ be a basis for K. We can assume that $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\alpha_k \geq 0$. Because (1) is false and $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\alpha_kv_k = 0$, we can conclude that $\alpha_i < 0$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$. We can also conclude that the vectors $v_1, \dots, v_{i - 1}, v_{i + 1}, \dots, v_n$ are linearly independent. Lets define $L$ such that $L(v_k) = -1$ for $k \neq i$. We have

$$L(v_i) = L(-\frac{1}{\alpha_i}\sum_{k \neq i}\alpha_kv_k) = \frac{\sum_{k \neq i}\alpha_k}{\alpha_i} \leq \frac{-\alpha_i}{\alpha_i} = -1$$

Comment: Is $L$ linear or affine?

Comment: $L$ is always linear

Comment: Then in this case, the proof is pretty immediate from the fact that the statement 1 is equivalent to saying that $0\in\mathbf{co}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.

Comment: @KBS can you give me hints? Please

Comment: Just draw the convex hull of the points and trace few of the linear forms. What do you observe? How can you formalize that?

Comment: In geometric terms, what I am trying to prove is that if a point $O$ doesn't belong to the convex hull of points $P_1, \dots, P_n$, then there exists an hyperplane that separates $O$ from $P_1, \dots, P_n$. That is, $O$ is on one side and $P_1, \dots, P_n$ on the other

Comment: The geometric picture is clear enough. The difficult part is translating this picture into a formal algebraic proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show that the first statement is equivalent to saying that $0\in\mathbf{co}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ or, equivalently, that there exist $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \geq 0$, $||\alpha||_1=\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n=1$, such that $$\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\alpha_kv_k = 0.$$ Obviously, this implies the first statement. To prove the converse just note that if the condition of the first statement holds for some $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \geq 0$, then it also holds for $\tilde\alpha_1, \dots, \tilde\alpha_n \geq 0$ where $\tilde\alpha_i=\alpha_i/||\alpha||_1$.

Now assume that the statement 1 does not hold and so, that $0\notin\mathbf{co}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. Define by $P$ that convex compact polytope and by $\tilde P$ its symmetric with respect to the origin. Since $0\notin P$ and $0\notin \tilde P$, then $P$ and $\tilde P$ are disjoint. By the hyperplane separation principle, there exists a functional $L(v)$ such that $L(v)>0$ on $\tilde P$, $L(v)<0$ on $P$ and $L(0)=0$.

Comment: By $P$ do you mean $\{ \sum_k \alpha_kv_k | \sum_k \alpha_k = 1 \}$? And by saying that $\tilde{P}$ is symmetric with respect to the origin, do you mean that $v \in \tilde{P} \iff -v \in P$?

Comment: Yes, we have $\{ \sum_k \alpha_kv_k | \sum_k \alpha_k = 1 \}=\mathbf{co}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.  And yes, by symmetric, I meant point symmetry, which in this case means that $\tilde P$ is $\mathbf{co}\{-v_1,\ldots,-v_n\}$. The idea is to construct another compact convex object and use the hyperplane separation theorem.